# Several function conditions

Tags: derivatives

It was told to me an exercise:

> Represent a continuous and differentiable function whose derivative is annulled in
>   points $A(-1, 4)$ and $B(2, -3)$ and that complies these conditions:
>
> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = -\infty\qquad \lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = +\infty$

But I found it very easy and I wanted to go further. My question is: *is there any to obtain the function $f(x)$*?

I've thought that:

- To simplify the problem, I considere that $f'(x)$ is only annulled in points $A$ and $B$, so $f'(x)$ is a 2nd grade equation.
- Due to that, $f(x)$ has to be a 3rd grade equation, so I say: $f(x)= ax^3+bx^2+cx+d, \qquad a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R$.
- Since $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$, I've got that $f'(x) =3ax^2+2bx +c$.
- Then, I can say the following:

  - Because $ A,B\in f\longrightarrow f(-1)=4$ and $f(2)=-3$.
  - And because $A$ and $B$ nullify the derivative of $f(x) \longrightarrow f'(-1)=0$ and $f'(2)=0$.
- If I pose the equations of that supositions, I've got that:

  $$ \left. \begin{array}{rl}4 &= a(-1)^3 + b(-1)^2 + c(-1) + d\\
  -3 &= a · 2^3 + b · 2^2 + c · 2 +d\\
  0&=3a(-1)^2 +2b(-1)+c\\
  0&=3a · 2^2 + 2b · 2 + c
   \end{array}\right\} =  \left. \begin{array}{rl}4 &= -a + b - c + d\\
  -3 &= 8a + 4b + 2c +d\\
  0&=3a  - 2b +c\\
  0&=12a + 4b + c
   \end{array}\right\}$$

but I can't find a way to solve this. Is there any way to get that function (or solve the system with another equation(s))? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: If $f'$ is a quadratic whose roots are $-1$ and $2$ then you know that $f'$ factors as $k(x+1)(x-2)$, where $k$ is any constant in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So how can I solve it, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $f'(x)=k_1(x+1)(x-2)$. We search for solutions of this specific form and if we don't find any, we'll try another form (try with an additional $(x-\alpha)$ factor or something else).

You get $f'(x)=k_1(x+1)(x-2)=k_1x^2-k_1x-2k_1$ so $f(x)=\cfrac{k_1}{3}x^3-\cfrac{k_1}{2}x^2-2k_1x+k_2$.

$4=f(-1)=-\cfrac{k_1}{3}-\cfrac{k_1}{2}+2k_1+k_2=\cfrac{7}{6}k_1+k_2$

$-3=f(2)=\cfrac{8k_1}{3}-2k_1-4k_1+k_2=-\cfrac{10}{3}k_1+k_2$

Do you know how to solve this linear system?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Ideally you would want to note the limit condition which requires $f$ to be of odd degree (as is the case here) and $k_1$ to be positive.